# Why hbox does not start a new paragraph?

Tags: tex-core, boxes, paragraphs

These two produce the same result:

```
abc
%\null
def
\bye
```

```
abc
\null
def
\bye
```

These two are different:

```
abc

%\null
def
\bye
```

```
abc

\null
def
\bye
```

Does anybody know where this behavior is documented in *The TeXbook*?

Comment: @cfr "so a paragraph break is inserted" - precision: it's inserted after `hbox`. But where exactly is this behavior described?

Comment: Actually, I have no idea.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [TeX Book](http://ctan.org/pkg/texbook) (Chapter **13 Modes**, p 86):

> **Exercise 13.1**:
>
> If you say `\hbox{...}` in horizontal mode, TeX will
>   construct the specified box and it will contribute the result to the
>   current paragraph. Similarly, if you say `\hbox{...}` in vertical mode,
>   TeX will construct a box and contribute it to the current page.
>   What can you do if you want to begin a paragraph with an `\hbox`?
>
> *Answer* (Appendix A: Answers to All Exercises, p 313):
>
> Simply saying `\hbox{...}` won't work, since that box will just
>   continue the previous vertical list without switching modes. You need
>   to start the paragraph explicitly, and the straightforward way to
>   do that is to say `\indent\hbox{...}`.
>   But suppose you want to define
>   a macro that expands to an `hbox`, where this macro is to be used in the
>   midst of a paragraph as well as at the beginning; then you don't want
>   to force users to type `\indent` before calling your macro at the
>   beginning of a paragraph, nor do you want to say `\indent` in the
>   macro itself (since that might insert unwanted indentations).  One
>   solution to this more general problem is to say
>   `\ \unskip\hbox{...}`, since `\`  makes the mode
>   horizontal while `\unskip` removes the unwanted space. Plain TeX
>   provides a `\leavevmode` macro, which solves this problem in what is
>   probably the most efficient way: `\leavevmode` is an abbreviation for
>   `\unhbox\voidbox`, where `\voidbox` is a permanently empty box register.